# wire:click call two methods at once

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with `wire:click` event and I want to know, how to call two methods on one click.
I have been tried several times without success, and I didn't found any information in the documentation
so my examples:

in this case return `method setItem is not defined`, but the method is defined in the Livewire Component

```
wire:click="$emitTo('assign-modal', 'show-assign-modal'); setItem({{$book->id}})"
```

second case:
in this case it's normal for me to not work, but I decided to give a chance and try what will happen

```
wire:click="$emitTo('assign-modal', 'show-assign-modal')" wire:click="setItem({{$book->id}})"
```

third case:
in this case I have been tried to call the method with custom event, but still without success

```
wire:click="$emitTo('assign-modal', 'show-assign-modal'); $emitSelf('setData', {{$book->id}})"
```

Also I have an another idea, to pass the data to the first custom event `assing-modal` and after that to return the data to the parent component, but I think this idea is awful, so any help will be appreacited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot call 2 function in  `wire:click`

so in this case you should do like this

```php
wire:click="setItem({{$book->id}})"
```

in component

```php
public function setItem($bookId)
{
    $emitTo('assign-modal', 'show-assign-modal'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: put a span enclosing the button with a `wire:clik` action, like this:

```
<span wire:click="printAll()">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="$emit('showLoader')">
        Print All ️
    </button>
</span>
```